# CUDA computeprof not working with Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, qt, cuda, profiler

I'm trying to use CUDA Computeprof (CUDA profiler) to profile a multithreading application.

I've got two threads implemented with Qt, each one of them using a different CUDA context. I'm using the CUDA Driver API. The profiler application detects CUDA calls from the first (main) thread only and completely ignore the calls from the other thread.

Does anyone have a workaround or a reason for this?

Comment: The visual profiler can only profile a single CUDA context at a time.

Comment: @talonmies Perhaps make it an answer?

Comment: @Bart: It is a comment because there was one "corner case" I haven't personally tested which qualifies the statement, and Brano seems to have confirmed it with his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use Nvidia Parallel Nsight to profile multithreaded applications. But i tested CUDA profiler on the MonteCarloMultiGPU SDK 3.2 example and it does indeed profile all CUDA context for the same session. I am using the CUDA profiler that came with CUDA 4.0.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case when the new multigpu implementation is used in CUDA >= 4.0, with multiple contexts held by a single thread. But the multithreaded, multiGPU case doesn't work (or at least it didn't on a lot of my pthreads based linear algebra code with multiple GPUs).

Comment: I tested the CUDA 3.2 version of MonteCarloMultiGPU. In the output when running in CUDA profiler i could see the output "launching x threads". So i guess it does work with multiple threads. The Visual profiler is still the one from CUDA 4.0